# How to know the number of CPUs and spec for each CPU/Core in Ubuntu Karmic?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardware, central-processing-unit

How to know the number of CPUs and spec for each CPU/Core in Ubuntu Karmic?

Answer (score 4):

I found it:  cat /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 0):

**[dmidecode](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode)** gives some good system information as well. Useful when debugging hardware issues.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer [lshw](http://ezix.org/software/lshw.html), which provides extremely detailed info, a wide choice of output forms (including a gui), and is packaged for Karmic (so you can install it with `apt-get install lshw`).